# What would be the easiest way to display a certain page in WebView offline?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making an app that opens a certain webpage with WebView. Normally, I would download the webpage manually and put it in assets and just open it with WebView from there, but the information that this website contains changes  a few times per month, that's why I want to keep it up to date.

But while keeping the site up to date, I also want my users to be able to access it while OFFLINE.

This is how I want it to work:

1. If the downloaded html file doesn't exist on external storage yet, download it
2. If there is no internet connection and the html file exists, display that html file
3. If there is internet connection and the html file also exists, display content from internet and replace the html file with the newer version

I did some research and all I could find is to save the WebView in cache but that isn't possible because the site I'm opening in WebView has caching disabled (I have no administration rights and I have no way to contact the website admin).

I've also done a lot of research on how to download and display html file with webview but there isn't any good example which I could rely on.

This is the page I'm trying to display and download: https://www.easistent.com/urniki/263/razredi/16515

Comment: It is an edge case but have you thought about when a user downloads the app but doesn't open it right away. Later they decide to open it without an internet connection... How will you handle that? You could package some HTML of the current page into the assets directory or show the user a message saying they need an internet connection. Just something to think about.

Comment: Yes, I've got that on my mind, my app will be available only for certain people though, there will be maximum 200-300 users, so it won't be a problem to tell those people how to use it properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the internet first (You can find many resolved question on S.O.), If there is internet connection, use HttpClient to get HTML source and save it to external storage. and Then load the webpage from external storage in webview. If no internet connection, simply load page in webview.

Code to save and update html source while internet is available:

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://yoururl.com"); // Set the action you want to do
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
 InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here
     is.close(); // Close the stream
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Path/to/save/file/index.html");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f1);
        p.print(resString);
        p.close();
        f1.close();

    }catch(IOException e){}
```

Edit : As @michaelcarrano says in comment, perform this work in background by using another thread.